# How to configure ssl for .net core on iis in production?

Tags: ssl, iis, amazon-ec2, production-environment

There are many docs or samples to run with self signed certificates for .net core development environment on iisexpress. But i have some problems on production environment.
I use .net core 2.0. I have valid ssl from a `let's encrypt` client for windows (Certify).

My production environment:
Windwos Server 2012 R2
IIS 8.5.x

I've added `services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => { options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); });` in `ConfigureServices`

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "MyProject.EndUser", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
    }
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

My app still works on http without anyproblem. But with https, it does not repond. What should i do?

## Update 1:

It looks like my problem is not about .net core. I've changed my web.config like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="api/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So static files will be handled by IIS. When I request a file over http it respond normal. But it still does not work over https.

I mean, http://myapp.com/static.htm responds normal. But https://myapp.com/static.htm does not respond and timeout.

Comment: Double-check the bindings and enabled protocols for your site in IIS. Are you sure your environment variable is set correctly? You could also add a redirect from HTTP-> HTTPS as per [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl#require-ssl)

Comment: It looks like my problem is not about .net core, its about iis. I've changed .net core handler configuration. And exclude static files from .netcore handler. Still it doesnt work on https. I am still working on it.

Comment: double check and stop the default site or any site having https binding (port 443) that is overriding your settings. Also try server name indicator checkbox in the https configuration.

Comment: I've stopped default site and problem still exist. How can I check other sites are overriding my settings? "server name indicator checkbox" does not affect anything.

Comment: I've checked all other sites bindings. There is no wildcard binding. Every sites has its own header.

Comment: How have you configure HTTPS in IIS?  What settings are you using?  Is the certifcate installed correctly?

Comment: I've checked certifcates from IIS > Server Certificates. They looks fine. What do you mean by "configure HTTPS in IIS". I didnt do anything on IIS.

Comment: Firstly, I've solved my problem. It was about amazon security policy.
Seconly, I'm sorry, i took your time :)

Solution: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/going-https-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-14-04-with-lets-encrypt-certbot-on-nginx-696770649e76